# Array modifier's coord. system

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]
I want to make array from sphere along line i marked red. I've already converted it into curve and choose it in "object" box of array modifier - didn't help.

As i understand, the coordinates of array modifier i marked red are global. Is there any way to make them different (local, for exemple)?

[image]

Comment: Did you try drawing a curve along the red line and use "Fit type" as "curve"?

Comment: I've tried - result is on second pic. Array didn't change it's direction.

Comment: What changed your mind about my answer? Could you comment please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a curve with 2 control points
2. `Edit mode`, change type to `Poli`
3. On the sphere, add an `Array Modifier` select `Fit Type=Curve` and select the curve as target object
4. add a `Deform/Curve` modifier select the curve as target

[image]

Comment: I still got troubles, please, see "2-nd situation" in my post. Do you know wich file storages are allowed here for i could upload my file?

Comment: So instead of first accepting my answer then refusing, then adding a 2nd problem. Could you please reaccept my post as answer if it solves your problem and create open a separate question? It is considered bad practice to asked multiple questions in one. Thanks.

Comment: also, use this to attach blend files: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: No problem. Here is my new question:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174413/curve-modifier-breaks-objects-position
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Curves in Blender are very particular and finicky. Lets say your curve is the Child of another object and that parent object is rotated, you try and array something on that curve and give it a 'curve' modifier, Hmmm its a no go. But if you array some object along a curve that has NO/NOT any transforms and parent it with 'curve deform' then you can translate the curve or curves parent how ever you like. As far as the Array modifiers 'Fit Curve' option goes, that arrays stuff just along the length of the curve - no more or less. If you can clear transforms on your objects and try the CTRL+P > Curve Deform, that will get you where you need to be, if not then try to parent the array object to the curve using 'Path Constraint', you may have to invert your array offset.