# Curve modifier breaks object's position

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I positioned cylinder on cube's face and want to make array of it along curve in the middle of cube's face:
[image] For that i use Array and Curve modifiers on cylinder, but every time i use Curve modifier, cylinder "jumps away", loses it's position and i don't know how to bring it back without cancelling Curve modifier:
[image]

Here is the file:[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is a problem with origin or your objects. I suggest to delete the cylinder and curve and recreate them at the World origin. Then only move the curve to the rectangular shape.

Comment: Hello :). Bruno is right. Also, your objects don't have applied rotation, which causes trouble on it's own. Good luck.

Comment: @Bruno
I deleted curve and cylinder and recreated them. Curve was moved to the face while cylinder was left at the World origin. The result of Curve modifier used is on 3-rd pic.

Comment: @Jachym Michal
Curve's and cylinder's origins are at the World origin. All transforms are applied. The result of Curve modifier used is on 3-rd pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your blend file:

1. Select the curve and `Apply All Transforms`
2. Create a new cylinder at the origin
3. Scale it to desire shape
4. `Apply All Transforms` on the cylinder
5. Add Array and Curve Modifier to cylinder
6. Select the curve, and in `Edit Mode` do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to adjust the tilt

[image]